# Heuristic Analysis - Kaspersky - Checkout Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, kaspersky

I have a store in Magento 1.9.3.6 and when I get to the checkout, kaspersky blocks with the data loss message, heuristic analysis, can someone tell me what it can be?

https://www.zapcountry.com.br[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM4XH.png)